# Is there anyway to embed a gmail or email client into a website?

Tags: html, reactjs, web

Working on a website and I want to integrate an "email" or messaging system into the website. It would be for messaging between the users/administrators of the website.

A bit more background, it is a website for a local project near me, I am creating it for the admins to be able to do everything they would need all within the website, so there would only be around 15-20 users max.

I was thinking something along the lines of a Gmail or email client integration with embedded html like you can do with Google maps, does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can use formspree with simple HTML form. Users can send messages to admin by formspree that sends the messages by email. You can examine formspree [there](https://formspree.io/)

Comment: Will definitely use that for the form portion of the website! Thank you, not exactly what I was looking for, in terms of a in-webiste messaging service between users but still helpful and will come in handy when I get to that!